# Public and dashboard css in the pipeline. loading different ones depending on page/signed_in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, assets

I have a css file for public pages and another for private pages. These files conflict, so I would only like to load one at a time, depending on whether or not the user is signed in.

Ideally, I'd like to keep this out of the controller. I am using Devise and CanCan

Can someone give me an example implementation please? If I must put it into each controller, then it's not the end of the world, I just assume there's more of a DRY way of carrying this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your layout file

```
<%- if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'dashboard', media: 'all' %>
<%- else %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```